# What is the first language to implement asterisk * as wild card character?

Tags: history, asterisk

I have been researching and trying to find the oldest possible implementation of the wildcards and how the asterisk * became the (almost) global standard when it come to represent a wildcard character.

There's many languages that use it that it's actually hard to find which used it first.

The Oldest possible language that i could find that has it was [TRAC language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRAC_(programming_language)). although am not sure when it was actually implemented.

Comment: If this gets closed here, retrocomputing.stackexchange might be friendlier.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star?wprov=sfla1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an answer as follows

> It was invented by Stephen Kleene around 1956 as part of the specifications for regular expressions; it's called the "Kleene star" or the "Kleene closure".
> —John Lawler in [english.stackexchange comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/118417/earliest-use-of-an-asterisk-to-indicate-a-zero-to-many-character-wildcard#comment242270_118417)